# Airflow Scheduling first of month

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I want to schedule a DAG at first of month at 5 AM UTC time. so lets say that I want to start running my DAG from 01/01/2021 5 AM . what should be my start date and schedule interval. I want the DAG run on 01/01/2021 to have the same execution date that is 01/01/2021. Any leads on how this could be achieved.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [FAQs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html#what-does-execution-date-mean) about `execution_date` may help you understand what's happening, (see also [DAG Runs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html#dag-runs)):

> Airflow was developed as a solution for ETL needs. In the ETL world, you typically summarize data. So, if you want to summarize data for 2016-02-19, You would do it at 2016-02-20 midnight UTC, which would be right after all data for 2016-02-19 becomes available.

Basically, the DAG with `execution_date = 2021-01-01T05:00:00+00:00`  will actually be executed one `schedule_interval` later (2021-02-01T05:00:00+00:00). The actual date the execution occurred, is represented in the `start_date` attribute of the "dag_run" object (you can access it through the execution context parameters). It is the same date that you can find in the Explore UI >> Dag Runs >> Start Date column.

Try creating a dummy DAG like the following:

```py
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator

args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
}

with DAG(
    dag_id="dummy_dag",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1, 5),
    schedule_interval="0 5 1 * *",
) as dag:

    t1 = DummyOperator(task_id="task_1")
```

After the first exeuction, you could play around with the CLI to calculate future execution dates:

```sh
~/airflow$ airflow dags next-execution dummy_dag -n 10 -h
usage: airflow dags next-execution [-h] [-n NUM_EXECUTIONS] [-S SUBDIR] dag_id

Get the next execution datetimes of a DAG.
It returns one execution unless the num-executions option is given
```

Let me know if that worked for you!

Comment: But when i schedule a DAG for let's say 01/01/2021 with interval of daily the behaviour is different , the DAG then gets executed on the next day and the execution date is of previous day. So why scheduling is different ?

Comment: The DAG scheduled 01/01/2021 with daily interval, will get executed, one interval after it's `start_date`, meaning, 02/01/2021. In the upcoming days, Airflow 2.2 will be released with important changes around the "scheduling dates" and naming, to make things more clear. In the mean time you can find the explanations and "whys" in the links a provided above, just remember to think about it as one interval delayed and thats it.